# Y or N statements in Batch files

Tags: batch-file

I am a dabbler in batch files so my knowledge is limited to my experiences. What I am trying to do is limit the "Y or N" inputs to just that Y or N. Right now you can put anything in the fields and the code progresses. What I am attempting to do is create a hotspot using a batch file. I have yet to figure out how to "save" the created network but that isn't really an issue.

I have included what I have, the lines being the start and finish, If anyone happens to see anything that can be improved upon or made less bulky feel free to comment.

```
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B
:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:-------------------------------------- 
@echo off
:SSID
set /P inputA="Input desired Network SSID:"
echo.
set /P c=Is %inputA% correct? [Y/N]?
echo.
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :PSWD
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :SSID
:PSWD
set /P inputB="Input desired 8 to 63 character Network Password:"
echo.
set /P c=Is %inputB% correct? [Y/N]?
echo.
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :SETUP
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :PSWD
:SETUP
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=%inputA% key=%inputB% >NUL
@echo Creating Network...
echo.
timeout /t 5 /nobreak > NUL
@echo Network Created!
echo.
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
set /P c=Would you like to start your new Network? [Press "Y" to continue/Press "N" to abort]
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :START
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :BYE
:START
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
timeout /t 5 /nobreak > NUL
@echo Your Network has started!
pause
:BYE
Exit
```

Comment: [choice](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html)

Comment: The answer to your question could easily have been found with a quick Google search. Please, do more research next time.

Comment: @MatthewHorvath With my education on this subject (piecemeal self teaching/adapting code I find online, and do not understand) relevant information isn't easily recognized.

Comment: That's how I taught myself. It wasn't easy, and I understand where you're coming from. However, you could try using different terms in google, or using a dictionary of commands (I personally use ss64.com/nt).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `set /p`, use the `choice` command. I, personally, would use:

```
choice /m Correct?
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto PSWD
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto SSID
```

This will display: `Continue? [Y/N]?`. If the hit y, it will go to `:PSWD`. If they hit n, it will go to `:SSID`.

The help section of the choice command (brought up in Command Prompt by `choice /?`)

```
CHOICE [/C choices] [/N] [/CS] [/T timeout /D choice] [/M text]

Description:
    This tool allows users to select one item from a list
    of choices and returns the index of the selected choice.

Parameter List:
   /C    choices       Specifies the list of choices to be created.
                       Default list is "YN".

   /N                  Hides the list of choices in the prompt.
                       The message before the prompt is displayed
                       and the choices are still enabled.

   /CS                 Enables case-sensitive choices to be selected.
                       By default, the utility is case-insensitive.

   /T    timeout       The number of seconds to pause before a default
                       choice is made. Acceptable values are from 0 to
                       9999. If 0 is specified, there will be no pause
                       and the default choice is selected.

   /D    choice        Specifies the default choice after nnnn seconds.
                       Character must be in the set of choices specified
                       by /C option and must also specify nnnn with /T.

   /M    text          Specifies the message to be displayed before
                       the prompt. If not specified, the utility
                       displays only a prompt.

   /?                  Displays this help message.

   NOTE:
   The ERRORLEVEL environment variable is set to the index of the
   key that was selected from the set of choices. The first choice
   listed returns a value of 1, the second a value of 2, and so on.
   If the user presses a key that is not a valid choice, the tool
   sounds a warning beep. If tool detects an error condition,
   it returns an ERRORLEVEL value of 255. If the user presses
   CTRL+BREAK or CTRL+C, the tool returns an ERRORLEVEL value
   of 0. When you use ERRORLEVEL parameters in a batch program, list
   them in decreasing order.

Examples:
   CHOICE /?
   CHOICE /C YNC /M "Press Y for Yes, N for No or C for Cancel."
   CHOICE /T 10 /C ync /CS /D y
   CHOICE /C ab /M "Select a for option 1 and b for option 2."
   CHOICE /C ab /N /M "Select a for option 1 and b for option 2."
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, snide remarks aside, it is very appreciated.